# Cannot install generated build apk from Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, apk

When i run app from android studio it will install directly to the device without any problem, but if i make build apk and try to install it says apk not installed.

Please find following video link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/15aKMjmgDrExRcEWzPuwe_lF67w6govp4/view

Thanks

Comment: Seems to be an issue with your emulator, try it on some other device.

Comment: No i have tested so many times with my mobile also its not installing, should i reinstall android studio???

Comment: while installing manually in emulator i got this on logcat 

"Invalid package archive file, can't add package name and send affiliate intent to Home services for local-apk install source"